# Which IC is this>?

Tags: integrated-circuit

Attached is a pic of a flowmeter. What company is this IC from?[image]

Comment: You should post a sharper picture and rotate it for out convenience. Now all the electrons are going to fall out.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be this one?

SGL chip for ultrasonic flow meter @ Alibaba

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/IC-transceiver-SGL-chip-for-ultrasonic_60717105695.html

Comment: Beat me to it by 17 seconds. :)

Comment: @PrudhviSagar Then please mark Tom's answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This IC is made by a Chinese company called Relmon. [Here](http://www.relmon.com/upload/0/20141010104941251.pdf) you can find its datasheet (unfortunately not in English). This IC is an equivalent of TDC-GP22 (Time to Digital Converter) with some additional features.